# Using For loop to get values of multiple elements in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop

The title is so general mainly because I don't know what should be the appropriate title for it. Let me just explain the situation:

Say that I have two textboxes named `LastName0` and `FirstName0` and a button called `addMore`. When I click `addMore`, another two textboxes will be created through JavaScript. These textboxes will be named `LastName1` and `FirstName1`. When I click the `addMore` button again, another two textboxes button will be created and named `LastName2` and `FirstName2` respectively. This will go on as long as the `addMore` button is clicked. Also, a button named `deleteThis` will be created alongside the textboxes. This simply deletes the created textboxes when clicked.

I also initialized a variable called `counter`. Every time the `addMore` button is clicked, the `counter` goes up by 1, and whenever the `deleteThis` button is clicked, the `counter` decreases by 1. The value of the `counter` is stored in a hidden input type.

When the user submits the form, I get the value of the `counter` and create a For loop to get all the values of the textboxes in the form. Here is the sample code:

```
//Suppose that the user decides to add 2 more textboxes. Now we have the following:
     // LastName0   FirstName0
     // LastName1   FirstName1
// LastName2    FirstName2

$ctr = $_POST['counter']; //the counter == 3
for ($x = 0; $x < $ctr; $ctr++)
{
    $lastname = $_POST["LastName$x"];
    $firstname = $_POST["FirstName$x"];

    //This will get the values of LastName0,1,2 and FirstName0,1,2

    //code to save to database…
}
```

On the code above, if the value of `counter` is equal to 3, then the values of textboxes `LastName0,1,2` and `FirstName0,1,2` will be saved. Now here is the problem: If the user decided to delete `LastName1` and `FirstName1`, the For loop will not be able to iterate properly:

```
$ctr = $_POST['counter']; //the counter == 2
for ($x = 0; $x < $ctr; $ctr++)
{
    //Only LastName0 and FirstName0 will be saved.

    $lastname = $_POST["LastName$x"];
    $firstname = $_POST["FirstName$x"];

    //code to save to database…
}
```

Someone told me to use the "push and pop" concept to solve this problem, but I am not really sure on how to apply it here. So if anyone can tell me how to apply it, it'll be grand.

Comment: $_POST[''] WILL RETURN ONLY FILLED FIELDS of FORM

Comment: Not related to problem, but you should look into input field arrays.

Comment: You have some logic problems here if people delete and add text boxes, when later values are already set. If I was to create 3 text boxes, populate them, and then delete the first set. When I add a new set in, I will have two sets of text boxes both called LastName2 and FirstName2 as my counter will have been de-incremented and then incremented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add your input text boxes with name as array ie, `<input type="text" name="FirstName[]" />`
2. In php you can fetch them as a array. ie,

   ```
    foreach($_POST["FirstName"] as $k=>$val){
       echo $val; // give you first name
       echo $_POST["LastName"][$k]; // will give you last ame
    }
   ```

In this case even if one set of field is removed in HTML will not affect the php code.

Comment: I didn't know that you can name an element with an array.Thanks for the tip! I'll try it and see if it'll work.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to use the isset function like this:

```
$ctr = $_POST['counter']; 
for ($x = 0; $x < $ctr; $ctr++)
{

isset($_POST["LastName$x"])?$lastname = $_POST["LastName$x"]:;
isset($_POST["FirstName$x"])?$firstname = $_POST["FirstName$x"]:;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, instead of using LastNameN and FirstNameN names try using LastName[N] and FirstName[N], this way the result is an array and you can iterate through it with a foreach, meaning you will not need the counter and the index of the value will not be important:

```
foreach ($_POST["LastName"] as $i=>$lastname) {
    if (!isset($_POST["FirstName"][$i])) {
        // This should only happen if someone messes with the client side before posting
        throw new Exception("Last name input does not have a related First name input");
    }   

    $firstname = $_POST["FirstName"][$i];
}
```

If not, then you may have to use your $counter in a different way

```
$current = 0;
while ($counter) { // Stop only when i found all
    if (isset($_POST["LastName$current"]) {
        $counter--;  // Found one
        $lastname =   $_POST["LastName$current"];
        $firstname = $_POST["FirstName$current"];
    }   
    $current++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A better way to solve this would be to use arrays for Firstname and Lastname. Instead of calling them Lastname0 and Firstname0, then Lastname1 and Firstname1, call them all Lastname[] and Firstname[]. Give them ID's of Lastname0 and Firstname0 and so on for the delete function, but keep the names as arrays.

When the form is submitted use the following:

```
foreach($_POST['Lastname'] as $i => $lastname) {
    $firstname = $_POST['Firstname'][$i]

    //... code to save into the database here
}
```

Be warned though that in IE if you have an empty field it will not be submitted, so if Lastname0 has a value, but Firstname0 does not, then $_POST['Firstname'][0] will in fact contain the value of Firstname1 (assuming it has a value in it). To get around this you can use javascript to check if a field is empty when submitting the form, and if so put the word EMPTY in it.

Answer (score 1):

**Do not use counter if not required**
A much easier way is to add array name when admore clicked.
Give a name like first_name[] in textbox

if you create form like that you can use foreach through `$_POST['first_name']`
try `var_dump($_POST)` in you php code to see how things goes on.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your for loop, maybe you could try...

> ```
> if ((isset($_POST["LastName$x"])) && (isset($_POST["FirstName$x"]))){
>     $lastname = $_POST["LastName$x"];
>     $firstname = $_POST["FirstName$x"];
>
>      //code to save to database…
> ```
>
> }

This will check if the variables exists before you try to do anything with them.